# Need help setting up RPM repositories from behind a proxy

Tags: proxy, redhat, rpm

I have a server at work running Redhat 7.6, but the internal repositories are always hopelessly out of date.  I've approached the security team who say they can whitelist a repository URL for me, but I'm having trouble finding one.  From what I can tell the process is automated somehow.  I'll be able to configure Yum to use the proxy, but can someone tell me where I can find the URL I need?

Answer (score 0):

It should be **cdn.redhat.com** per this KB article.

> In some cases, your firewall may be blocking access to the CDN URLs, which would result in `yum` being unable to complete downloads from Red Hat. In this case, your current firewall settings will need to be updated if you wish to download content from the CDN utilizing Red Hat Subscription Management.

[Public CIDR Lists for Red Hat (IP Addresses for cdn.redhat.com)](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1525183)

Comment: This information is hidden behind a subscription/paywall

Comment: I realize that and quoted the relevant part. Besides that, as a paying Red Hat customer you should have access anyway.